# Survey123 not exporting Headers/Labels/Text

Tags: labeling, excel, arcgis-survey123

I have been having this issue all day and I have tried every work around I can think of.

I am creating a form for technicians to use in the field to avoid using a field notebook.

For this site, we know each Well that will be gauged and we know some data (Top of Casing, Depth to Bottom, etc. are unique to each well) associated with each well that is used to configure calculations.

So (having not used this software too much) I decided to put each Well into their own group so the field techs have very little to do (was avoiding them having to type in Well ID's on their own and therefore have them pre-determined already). The first time I tried it, I started a group and then made the label for the 'begin group' the "Well ID" (i.e. S-315), but when I published the survey and then exported it to Excel, the S-315 was nowhere to be found on the excel sheet (it was not a Label like the rest of the columns). I tried it again as a 'select_one well_ID' and again the Well ID was nowhere to be found when I exported to excel. I tried it again as a pre-determined note and again the Well ID (i.e. S-315) was nowhere to be found when I exported it to Excel. I really do not understand what is going on because everything else is working great with the form, other than the fact when I export it to Excel I do not know which section is for which well because the Well ID does not carry over.

Attached, I have a screenshot of the published survey data as it appears through AGOL and the bottom window (which is set-up like an excel sheet) does not contain Well ID's anywhere, but when you look on the window to the right after clicking on that submission, it comes up with the bolded Well ID title and label, similar to how I need the excel sheet to export.

I also attached the screenshot

[image]

excel sheet to show what it looks like when I export it from AGOL.

Also attached is a screenshot of my excel sheet from the specific Survey123 Form I am having issues with, so you can see all of the 'survey', 'choices' you may want to see.

[image: excel choices]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you can only do this via ArcGIS Desktop or Pro. The roles in Survey123 need to be creator to be able to export https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2018/11/29/understanding-user-types-a-survey123-for-arcgis-guide

Comment: @Mapperz I am using a 'Creator' license through our ESRI account to create these Survey123 form (I downloaded the apps on a tablet and signed into our account that has a creator license and have been making them that way).

Comment: What is the setting for your bind::esri:fieldType setting on the select?  It looks like everything is ok on the select front and groupings, but if you are not seeing them in the feature class and export, check what fields they are supposed to be.  you can have fields in your survey that are not stored in the feature class.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that there is no field type specified for your bind::esri:fieldType setting.  This is the setting that determines which fields are created in the feature class.  Setting that to say a string or something should solve your issue.

Looking through your survey I am seeing a lot of repeated information and I would like to propose a slightly different approach.  your method will work great, but the data will be hard to parse, columns will be mixed and matched and it will be difficult to sort out any information except by hand. not a huge issue if you are only using excel and have one site, and still way better than field books and transposition back at the office.

I did a similar SWL project and used a repeat.  repeats create a related table so you would have a single point for each well that would store basic information that remains constant such as rim elev and depth to bottom.  Then each of your DTW and SWL measurement are stored in a one to many related table.

here is the xls form, notice the repeat, thats where the magic is.

[image]

and here is what the form looks like

[image]

The upper information can be locked as read only so you don't mess with it, and you can allow for viewing older measurements or let the field workers edit it or even just return a subset query.

basically this way you can give your workers a map and it will show the closest well. they click that well and bam just fill in the measurement. Then all that data is stored and easily queried in a more normalized format.

**you will have to enable the inbox on the setting tab of Survey123 for this to work**

Here is a blog from Ismael Chivite on how to do this.  He is the master of Survey123

https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2020/04/09/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-repeats